# What do Rails models have to do with the process of migrations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, schema, rake, database-schema

In this [article](http://icebergist.com/posts/rake-db-migrate-vs-rake-db-schema-load/), I don't understand what is the problem if you run `rake db:migrate` instead of `rake db:schema:load`. The author says it is

> because for your first migration “create_posts” it is necessary that
>   you have defined translatable attributes :title and :text in Post
>   model, but you removed :title from Post model translations.

But why is it necessary for you to have "defined translatable attributes :title and :text in Post model"? If you're just running migrations, what does that have to do with your model files? The migrations and db does not check your model files for anything do they? Running `rake db:migrate` just simply looks through **only** your migrations and translates those rails methods inside into SQL commands to build out a new db for you and then generates a new `schema.rb` file for you right? Why does it matter what is in your models?

Answer (score 1):

> But why is it necessary for you to have "defined translatable attributes :title and :text in Post model"? If you're just running migrations, what does that have to do with your model files?

Firstly, a migration file is just a ruby file. You can write whatever **code** inside it:

**Type of codes in migration files:**

1. usually they are **migration methods** like `create_table` or `add_column`.

   - these are agnostic of your model, which means these do not care about your model. Try deleting your model file, and run your `create_table` migration file using `rake db:migrate`, and you'll notice it succeeds without error.
2. sometimes, they are strongly-coupled / dependent to the contents of your current **model** file (or can depend on aaaany code actually). These are **not** the default Rails migration methods, and usually are API methods of one or more of your **gems** or even your own code implementation (if any). In your example, looking at the [article](http://icebergist.com/posts/rake-db-migrate-vs-rake-db-schema-load/), I noticed a non-Rails migration method:

   ```
   class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
     def up
       create_table :posts do |t|
         t.timestamps
       end

       # this is not a Rails migration method
       Post.create_translation_table! title: :string, text: :text
     end
   end
   ```

   - for `Post.creation_translation_table!` above which I assumed is a method from the **globalize** gem, because it is not a Rails migration method, we cannot be certain if that code depends on "something" from your current code. I can just assume that the command above is just that, because the article said

     > you will get BIG ERROR!
   - this is why the article said to use `rake db:schema:load` rather than `rake db:migrate` when migrating from a fresh database:

     - because `rake db:migrate` runs **WHATEVER** all code inside each of the migration files
     - while `rake db:schema:load` just runs one file, and it is the `schema.rb` which is just plain database information, and has no alien code that could disrupt / raise an error.
     - although... I might actually update the "BROKEN" migration files just so that `rake db:migrate` would run normally, provided that I am certain that the migration errors are traced from lines of non-Rails-methods that are dependent on a particular version of my code.

Comment: so you're saying that the globalize gem will likely reference the model file, so it's just safer to run structure:load?

Comment: Most likely yes. However, just to make sure, I read through the globalize gem readme, and found out exactly that `.create_translation_table!` method depends on model code (see [here](https://github.com/globalize/globalize#creating-translation-tables)), I quote: "Also note that before you can create a translation table, you have to define the translated attributes via translates in your model as shown above."

Comment: It will be "safer" only if you also have another migration file that: "removes :title from `posts_translations` table" and that you have run this migration file as well at the immediate time when you remove `:title` from Post model. See [dir.down from the docs](https://github.com/globalize/globalize#adding-additional-fields-to-the-translation-table) to see how you can you create a migration file that would remove a translatable attribute. This is important, because after you run this said migration file, it will update your `schema.rb` so that `post_translations` table will no longer...

Comment: ... have the column `:title`, and remember... that `schema.rb` is what `rake db:schema:load` just runs. Meaning, if you don't have this removal-migration-file, your `schema.rb` will be out of sync, and therefore when you create a fresh new database, and run `rake db:schema:load`, that database will be out of sync, though yes it will work (at least for now provided you won't add :title again in the future, because that will break that future migration run).